# How to cut down/delete part of a zarr array

Tags: zarr

I have a simple array (say length 1000) of objects in zarr. I want to replace it with a slimmed down version, picking only a subset of the items, as specified using a boolean array of size 1000. I want to keep everything else the same (e.g. if this array is a persistent one, I want to change the array on disk as well as in memory).

I can't simply reassign the array:

`my_zarr_data = my_zarr_data[:][selected_items]`

Because then I get the error `ValueError: missing object_codec for object array`.

Another option would be to make a copy, delete all the data, then add it back from the original using `append()`, but I can't see how to *clear* a zarr array while keeping the object_codec and other params the same (perhaps I could just do `resize(0)`?).

At the moment I'm resizing to the length of `sum(selected_items)` and then using `my_zarr_data.set_basic_selection(...,  my_zarr_data[:][selected_items])`.

Is that right? Is there a more efficient way to permanently reassign an array to (say) the return value from `get_mask_selection()`?

Comment: Suggest raising this as an issue on GitHub, ValueError suggests a bug. If you could provide a minimal reproducible example that causes the ValueError that would be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks @alistair-miles. Opened at https://github.com/zarr-developers/zarr-python/issues/502. The follow up question is whether it is possible to (efficiently) shrink a zarr array in-place by subsetting (e.g. using a boolean mask), rather than by using `resize()` and then `set_basic_selection()` to replace the entire array in one swoop?